# Error in \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, luatex

My code is as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[hyper,7x9]{times}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.2]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand{\sfbfit}[1]{\slantbox{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test \sfbfit{N}-count}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `\sfbfit` then everything works fine, please suggest what went wrong, please.

All the class file related things are available at https://mitpress.mit.edu/latex-and-tex-guidelines

I want to keep the character `N` in `bold-italic` face in chapter title, but in that particular font `Syntax` family, `bold-italic` was not available, so I made fake bold-italic, if I give that tag in chapter title then some error is coming, this is my problem, please advise what went wrong in my code.

Comment: Please reduce this to only what is needed for this problem. This is a good exercise when debugging.

Comment: And define your macros in the preamble not in the middle of the document. In the `.toc` we see `\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Test \bgroup \slantbox {N}\egroup -count}{3}` so `\tableofcontents` tries to execute `\slantbox` but it cannot because you define `\slantbox` **after** you run `\tableofcontents`

Comment: @daleif Sorry, I've updated the question, can you help me what went wrong in my code? as I'm in critical situation....

Comment: Seems to me your question is about something else now. Please explain what the end goal of that code is suppose to be. And as mentioned in my first comment, reduce to only what is needed.

Comment: @daleif I updated my question now, please advise...

Comment: You are still not explaining what it is you are trying to do, it is still not obvious from the code.  And now you are using a non standard class with no link to it. Make things work with a standard class first, then move to others. I my opinion, if you are a new user, why are you messing with stuff like this when you clearly does not understand it (even I don't understand your code)

Comment: @daleif Sorry, class file link was given now, the issue is I want to keep the character `N` in bold italic face, but in that particular font `Syntax` family, bold-italic was not available, so I made fake bold-italic, if I give that tag in chapter title then some error is coming, this is my actual problem...

Comment: @daleif Hope I've corrected the question as per you instructed...please help...

Comment: Any suggestions??? Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the tag `\@chapter` solved the issue...Thanks to `dalief`